# (react-scroll) (react-router) not working in same Component because both have <Link>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

```
Respected sir , I have to Use (react-scroll) (react-router)  both 
in same component but problem is both have Link

Example :- 
import {Link} from "react-scroll";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link  } from "react-router-dom";

My Question is , here I import Link twice , so how to use both Link in same component , 
can i write alias name of Link or Any Alternative of Link is possible

Example :-
import {Link as scrollLink} from "react-scroll";


<scrollLinkto={menu.children}>{menu.children}</scrollLink>



Please help me Sir I am new in reactjs.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following for the react-scroll import. You can actually name it anything you want.

```
import {Link as ScrollLink} from "react-scroll";
```